# actionscript2 load json from url

Tags: php, json, actionscript, actionscript-2

What is the right way to load json data from URL / php-script ?

I've tried:

```
var my_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
my_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
                trace( unescape(my_lv.toString()) )
    } else {
                trace("Error loading/parsing LoadVars.");
    }
};
my_lv.load(  "example.com/script.php"  );
```

But it adds extra data: **=&onLoad=[type Function]** to output.

Please.. help me.